# Настройка туннеля VPN

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, iptables

Подскажите как настроить такую конфигурацию:

Есть сервер с ssh (1), он должен быть соединен с сервером vpn(2), а клиент должен подключатся к серверу ssh(1) но через сервер 2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавить port forwarding SSH порта с IP адреса ServerSSH внутри VPN сети на внешний интерфейс ServerVPN

Comment: с чем у вас проблема? как я понял, с прокладкой соединительных кабелей.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin проблема в том что сервер стоит дома, но я не хотел бы подключать внешний ip для доступа к нему, и у меня есть инстанс на digiatl ochean вот он и будет входящим узлом

Comment: `$ man ssh`, опция `-R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, доступ по ключам.

Просто залогинится на vpn-2:

```
~[user@client-1] ssh user@jump-vpn-1 "ssh user@vpn-2"
```

Если нужно достучатся до сервиса по порту 443, доступному только с vpn2, перекинув на локальный 8443:

```
~[user@client-1] ssh  -L 8443:localhost:443 user@jump-vpn-1 "ssh -L 443:service-ip:443 user@vpn-2"
```

после чего, **service-ip:443** будет доступен локально по **localhost:8443**

Answer (score 1):

Здесь удобно использовать ключ -W для проброса потоков ввода-вывода.

При использовании этого метода, вы не раскрываете ключи для подключения к серверу 1 промежуточному серверу 2.

Например, в вашем случае, для быстрого подключения можно добавить следующую конфигурацию в .ssh/config:

```
Host srv1
    HostName srv1.example.com
    Port 22001
    User ivan
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ivan
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p vpn_user@srv2.example.com -p 22002 -i ~/.ssh/vpn_user
```

Тогда `ssh srv1` будет подключать вас как ivan к серверу 1, при этом сервер 2 будет выступать в качестве прокси.